# Conditional pairwise calculations in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example, I have 2 dfs:

df1

```
ID,col1,col2
1,5,9
2,6,3
3,7,2
4,8,5
```

and another df is

df2

```
ID,col1,col2
1,11,9
2,12,7
3,13,2
```

I want to calculate first pairwise subtraction from df2 to df1. I am using `scipy.spatial.distance` using a function `subtract_`

```
def subtract_(a, b):
    return abs(a - b)

d1_s = df1[['col1']]
d2_s = df2[['col1']]

dist = cdist(d1_s, d2_s, metric=subtract_)

dist_df = pd.DataFrame(dist, columns= d2_s.values.ravel())
print(dist_df)

 11   12   13
6.0  7.0  8.0
5.0  6.0  7.0
4.0  5.0  6.0
3.0  4.0  5.0
```

Now, I want to check, these new columns name like `11,12` and `13`. I am checking if there is any values in this new `dataframe` less than 5. If there is, then I want to do further calculations. Like this.
For example, here for columns name `'11'`, less than 5 value is 4 which is at `rows 3`. Now in this case, I want to subtract columns name `('col2')` of `df1` but at row 3, in this case it would be value `2`. I want to subtract this value 2 with `df2(col2)` but at row 1 (because column name `'11'`) was from value at row 1 in `df2`.

My `for loop` is so complex for this. It would be great, if there would be some easier way in pandas. 
Any help, suggestions would be great.

The expected new dataframe is this

```
0,1,2
Nan,Nan,Nan
Nan,Nan,Nan
(2-9)=-7,Nan,Nan
(5-9)=-4,(5-7)=-2,Nan
```

Comment: in the case of `l1`, you also have `row 4` that is under 5, what would be result, do you accumulate your calculation?

Comment: @Ben.T, yes whenever the values is less than 5, then subtraction should happen. If it is more than 5, then no subtraction, simply NaN would be enough in the final dataframe.

Comment: How did you get the value `2` to subtract? What happens with value `3` at row `4` of the distance matrix? Would you subtract some value from `df2.col2` because of this value `3` as well?

Comment: @QuangHoang value 2 subtract is because in dataframe dist_df, for col11, there is 4 which is less than 5. But 4 is at row 3 so, the subtraction happens with row3 at df1 for col2 which is value 2. But value 4 was for column name 11 which is at row1 in df2, so the value to subtract from df2 will be at row1 for col2.

Comment: It's better you include your expected outcome.

Comment: @QuangHoang, I have updated expected dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to Ben's answer, but with `np.where`:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.where(dist_df<5, df1.col2.values[:,None] - df2.col2.values, np.nan),
             index=dist_df.index,
             columns=dist_df.columns)
```

Output:

```
    11   12  13
0  NaN  NaN NaN
1  NaN  NaN NaN
2 -7.0  NaN NaN
3 -4.0 -2.0 NaN
```

Comment: great, thanks. This is exactly what I needed. I was using for loop, which was too much mess :D

Answer (score 1):

In your case using `numpy` with `mask`

```
df.mask(df<5,df-(df1.col2.values[:,None]+df2.col2.values))
Out[115]: 
     11   12   13
0   6.0  7.0  8.0
1   5.0  6.0  7.0
2  -7.0  5.0  6.0
3 -11.0 -8.0  5.0
```

Update

```
Newdf=(df-(-df1.col2.values[:,None]+df2.col2.values)-df).where(df<5)
Out[148]: 
    11   12  13
0  NaN  NaN NaN
1  NaN  NaN NaN
2 -7.0  NaN NaN
3 -4.0 -2.0 NaN
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is it possible to keep this new calculation in totally new dataframe.  It would be more easier for me for further calculation. if there is no subtraction, then we can simply put Nan.

Comment: @user3280146 please check

Comment: you have -11 and -8, they should be -4 and -2 :)

Comment: @user3280146 hehe , you explanation is confused